# Animate button while performing action Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a button that performs an action that takes 3 seconds (reads data from an API and refreshes the screen). While the action is performed, I would like the button to rotate.
My problem is that it starts to rotate AFTER the 3seconds operation has been completed...
and, ofc it stops immediately, as it hits ClearAnimation..

Here's my code

```
this.refreshButton.Click += this.RefreshPendingOrders_Click;



 private void RefreshPendingOrders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.StartRotateAnimation();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        this.refreshButton.ClearAnimation();
    }

    private void StartRotateAnimation()
    {
        
            var pivotX = this.refreshButton.Width / 2;
            var pivotY = this.refreshButton.Height / 2;
            var animation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, pivotX, pivotY)
            {
                Duration = 500,
                RepeatCount = 3
            };

            this.refreshButton.StartAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Comment: The call to `Thread.Sleep()` blocks the thread, in case of a Click it will be the UI thread. This is why you won't see the animation, since the thread it would animate on is blocked.

Comment: Don't call Thread.Sleep.

Comment: I have created two tasks, one that starts the animation, one that does the business, and I am awaiting them both. Now the problem is that after the animation is finished and it wants to stop it, it gives error Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'       - because it was started from another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `Thread.Sleep()` which in case of a Click EventHandler will be happening on the UI thread. This means you are blocking the UI Thread, which is responsible for running your animations for 3 seconds.

You could change your code to use async/await instead like:

```
private async void RefreshPendingOrders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartRotateAnimation();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    this.refreshButton.ClearAnimation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works like this. But what if I have a Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ... and inside I want to modify a view from the layout, how would that be possible, without getting the error Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.?

Comment: Just call `RunOnUiThread(() => { ui updates here });`. Also don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Cheesebaron, you were really helpful with that RunOnUiThread.

Comment: Oh, I am a little puzzled, though, about why is Task.Run preferable. As far as I remember, Task.Run was actually a particular case of Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: If you are running async code inside of `Task.Factory.StartNew` it will wrap it within another Task. Hence, in most cases `Task.Run` is preferable.